# SyntaxError: invalid syntax when using "while loop" in code using ZSS library for comparing two code

Tags: python, tree, abstract-syntax-tree, edit-distance

**I am computing Tree-Edit-Distance b/w two codes using ZSS library. When using while loop in any code it throws an error named Invalid syntax. It works fine with for loop. I am using [a link]https://github.com/timtadh/zhang-shasha for this.**

```
jk@JK-95:~/AnyLearn$ python any.py 
TranslationUnitDecl 0x301f980 <<invalid sloc>>
|-TypedefDecl 0x301fe80 <<invalid sloc>> __int128_t '__int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x301fee0 <<invalid sloc>> __uint128_t 'unsigned __int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x3020230 <<invalid sloc>> __builtin_va_list '__va_list_tag [1]'
`-FunctionDecl 0x30202d0 <tempAST:2:1, line:9:1> main 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x30688f0 <line:2:12, line:9:1>
    |-DeclStmt 0x30203f8 <line:3:2, col:12>
    | `-VarDecl 0x3020380 <col:2, col:10> i 'int'
    |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x30203d8 <col:10> 'int' 10
    |-DeclStmt 0x3020498 <line:4:2, col:12>
    | `-VarDecl 0x3020420 <col:2, col:10> j 'int'
    |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x3020478 <col:10> 'int' 20
    |-DeclStmt 0x30205c0 <line:5:2, col:11>
    | `-VarDecl 0x30204c0 <col:2, col:10> k 'int'
    |   `-BinaryOperator 0x3020598 <col:8, col:10> 'int' '*'
    |     |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x3020568 <col:8> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
    |     | `-DeclRefExpr 0x3020518 <col:8> 'int' lvalue Var 0x3020380 'i' 'int'
    |     `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x3020580 <col:10> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
    |       `-DeclRefExpr 0x3020540 <col:10> 'int' lvalue Var 0x3020420 'j' 'int'
    |-DeclStmt 0x3020668 <line:6:2, col:9>
    | `-VarDecl 0x30205f0 <col:2, col:8> z 'int'
    |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x3020648 <col:8> 'int' 0
    |-WhileStmt 0x3068888 <line:7:5, col:26>
    | |-<<<NULL>>>
    | |-BinaryOperator 0x30687a8 <col:11, col:13> 'int' '<'
    | | |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x3068790 <col:11> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
    | | | `-DeclRefExpr 0x3020680 <col:11> 'int' lvalue Var 0x30205f0 'z' 'int'
    | | `-IntegerLiteral 0x3068770 <col:13> 'int' 8
    | `-CompoundStmt 0x3068860 <col:15, col:26>
    |   |-UnaryOperator 0x30687f8 <col:17, col:18> 'int' postfix '++'
    |   | `-DeclRefExpr 0x30687d0 <col:17> 'int' lvalue Var 0x30205f0 'z' 'int'
    |   `-UnaryOperator 0x3068840 <col:22, col:23> 'int' postfix '++'
    |     `-DeclRefExpr 0x3068818 <col:22> 'int' lvalue Var 0x30204c0 'k' 'int'
    `-ReturnStmt 0x30688d0 <line:8:2, col:9>
      `-IntegerLiteral 0x30688b0 <col:9> 'int' 0

TranslationUnitDecl 0x26af980 <<invalid sloc>>
|-TypedefDecl 0x26afe80 <<invalid sloc>> __int128_t '__int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x26afee0 <<invalid sloc>> __uint128_t 'unsigned __int128'
|-TypedefDecl 0x26b0230 <<invalid sloc>> __builtin_va_list '__va_list_tag [1]'
`-FunctionDecl 0x26b02d0 <tempAST_file_:2:1, line:9:5> main 'int ()'
  `-CompoundStmt 0x26f8840 <line:2:12, line:9:5>
    |-DeclStmt 0x26b03f8 <line:3:2, col:12>
    | `-VarDecl 0x26b0380 <col:2, col:10> i 'int'
    |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x26b03d8 <col:10> 'int' 10
    |-DeclStmt 0x26b0498 <line:4:2, col:12>
    | `-VarDecl 0x26b0420 <col:2, col:10> j 'int'
    |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x26b0478 <col:10> 'int' 20
    |-DeclStmt 0x26b0538 <line:5:2, col:9>
    | `-VarDecl 0x26b04c0 <col:2, col:8> k 'int'
    |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x26b0518 <col:8> 'int' 0
    |-BinaryOperator 0x26b0620 <line:6:2, col:10> 'int' '='
    | |-DeclRefExpr 0x26b0550 <col:2> 'int' lvalue Var 0x26b04c0 'k' 'int'
    | `-BinaryOperator 0x26b05f8 <col:6, col:10> 'int' '*'
    |   |-ImplicitCastExpr 0x26b05c8 <col:6> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
    |   | `-DeclRefExpr 0x26b0578 <col:6> 'int' lvalue Var 0x26b0380 'i' 'int'
    |   `-ImplicitCastExpr 0x26b05e0 <col:10> 'int' <LValueToRValue>
    |     `-DeclRefExpr 0x26b05a0 <col:10> 'int' lvalue Var 0x26b0420 'j' 'int'
    |-DeclStmt 0x26f87e8 <line:7:5, col:12>
    | `-VarDecl 0x26f8770 <col:5, col:11> z 'int'
    |   `-IntegerLiteral 0x26f87c8 <col:11> 'int' 0
    `-ReturnStmt 0x26f8820 <line:8:2, col:9>
      `-IntegerLiteral 0x26f8800 <col:9> 'int' 0

File "counter.py", line 4
    Paticular = (Node(''' Trans ''').addkid(Node(''' TypedefDecl   __int128_t '__int128' ''')).addkid(Node(''' TypedefDecl   __uint128_t 'unsigned __int128' ''')).addkid(Node(''' TypedefDecl   __builtin_va_list '__va_list_tag [1]' ''')).addkid(Node(''' FunctionDecl 'int ()' ''').addkid(Node(''' CompoundStmt   ''').addkid(Node(''' DeclStmt   ''').addkid(Node(''' VarDecl 'int' ''').addkid(Node(''' IntegerLiteral   'int' 10 ''')))).addkid(Node(''' DeclStmt   ''').addkid(Node(''' VarDecl 'int' ''').addkid(Node(''' IntegerLiteral   'int' 20 ''')))).addkid(Node(''' DeclStmt   ''').addkid(Node(''' VarDecl 'int' ''').addkid(Node(''' BinaryOperator   'int' '*' ''').addkid(Node(''' ImplicitCastExpr   ''').addkid(Node(''' DeclRefExpr ' 'int' '''))).addkid(Node(''' ImplicitCastExpr   ''').addkid(Node(''' DeclRefExpr ' 'int' ''')))))).addkid(Node(''' DeclStmt   ''').addkid(Node(''' VarDecl 'int' ''').addkid(Node(''' IntegerLiteral   'int' 0 ''')))).addkid(Node(''' WhileStmt   ''').addkid(Node('''  '''))).addkid(Node(''' BinaryOperator   'int' '<' ''').addkid(Node(''' ImplicitCastExpr   ''').addkid(Node(''' DeclRefExpr ' 'int' '''))).addkid(Node(''' IntegerLiteral   'int' 8 '''))).addkid(Node(''' CompoundStmt   ''').addkid(Node(''' UnaryOperator   'int' postfix '++' ''').addkid(Node(''' DeclRefExpr ' 'int' '''))).addkid(Node(''' UnaryOperator   'int' postfix '++' ''').addkid(Node(''' DeclRefExpr ' 'int' '''))))).addkid(Node(''' ReturnStmt   ''').addkid(Node(''' IntegerLiteral   'int' 0 '''))))))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: File Counter.py ---> http://pastebin.com/uJSYZXi5

Comment: As currently presented, this question will be difficult for people to answer.  You may get more responses using some of the tips here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Put the relevant section of your code **here**, that's StackOverflow's rule.

Comment: I apologize sir, I am new here.  i will surely do that.

Comment: It looks like line 4 has an extra `)` at the end

Comment: http://pastebin.com/2QHBEvHV  I have to compile this file and get the answer so after removing that extra paren in counter.py , when i compile this file it generates the same probelm again in counter.py. :(